# Rust equivalent of mkdir -p

Tags: rust, filesystems, mkdir

What's the Rust equivalent of `mkdir -p <dir>`? The `-p` flag tells `mkdir` to create any missing parent directories as needed, and also not to error if `<dir>` already exists.

Is there any easy way to do this with the Rust standard library?

Comment: You know you're allowed to [search](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=mkdir) and read the documentation before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is [`create_dir_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html).

```rs
std::fs::create_dir_all(dir_path)
```